# Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createMovement GraphQL

Tags: sql, reactjs, typescript, graphql

I am currently building a React/Postgres/Graphql application in which i encounter the error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field Mutation.createMovement, whenever i try to execute the mutation in the FE. I am using appolo client for GQL. Any support would be helpful Here are my files.
Frontend

```
//index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
import client from './client';
import App from './App'; 

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```
//App.tsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useQuery, useMutation, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const GET_MOVEMENTS = gql`
  query {
    movements {
      id
      name
      musclesTrained
    }
  }
`;

const CREATE_MOVEMENT = gql`
  mutation CreateMovement($name: String!, $musclesTrained: [String!]!) {
    createMovement(name: $name, musclesTrained: $musclesTrained) {
      id
      name
      musclesTrained
    }
  }
`;

const App = () => {
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_MOVEMENTS);
  const [createMovement] = useMutation(CREATE_MOVEMENT);

  const [newMovementName, setNewMovementName] = useState("");
  const [newMusclesTrained, setNewMusclesTrained] = useState("");

  const handleCreateMovement = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await createMovement({
        variables: {
          name: newMovementName,
          musclesTrained: newMusclesTrained.split(","),
        },
      });

      if (data && data.createMovement) {
        console.log("Created movement:", data.createMovement);

        refetch();
      } else {
        console.error("Failed to create movement. No data returned.");
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      console.error("Error creating movement:", error.message);
    }
  };

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error: {error.message}</p>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h2>Create a New Movement</h2>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input
            type="text"
            value={newMovementName}
            onChange={(e) => setNewMovementName(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Muscles Trained (comma-separated):
          <input
            type="text"
            value={newMusclesTrained}
            onChange={(e) => setNewMusclesTrained(e.target.value)}
          />
        </label>
        <button onClick={handleCreateMovement}>Create Movement</button>
      </div>

      <h2>Movements</h2>
      {data.movements.map((movement: any) => (
        <div key={movement.id}>
          <h3>{movement.name}</h3>
          <p>Muscles Trained: {movement.musclesTrained.join(", ")}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```
//client.ts
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache } from "@apollo/client";

const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: "http://localhost:4000", 
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});

export default client;
```

Backend

```
//database.sql
CREATE DATABASE gym_tracker;

CREATE TABLE movements (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
  muscles_trained VARCHAR (255)[] NOT NULL
);
```

```
//db.ts
import * as pg from 'pg'

const { Pool } = pg

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  database: "gym_tracker",
  password: "pass",
  port: 5432,
});

export default pool;
```

```
//index.ts
import { ApolloServer } from "@apollo/server";
import { startStandaloneServer } from "@apollo/server/standalone";
import { typeDefs } from "./schema";
import pool from "./db";

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    movements: async () => {
      const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM movements");
      return result.rows;
    },
    movement: async (_: any, { id }: any) => {
      const result = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM movements WHERE id = $1", [
        id,
      ]);
      return result.rows[0];
    },
  },
  Mutation: {
    createMovement: async (_, { name, musclesTrained }) => {
      try {
        const result = await pool.query(
          "INSERT INTO movements (name, musclesTrained) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *",
          [name, musclesTrained]
        );
        return result.rows[0];
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("Failed to create movement");
      }
    },
  },
};

const main = async () => {
  const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
  });

  await startStandaloneServer(server, {
    listen: { port: 4000 },
  });
};

main();
```

```
schema.ts
export const typeDefs = `#graphql

type Movement {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    musclesTrained: [String!]!
}

type Exercise {
    id: ID!
    movement: Movement!
    repetions: Int!
    weight: Int!
    rest: Int!
}

type Workout {
    id: ID!
    exercises: [Exercise!]!
}

type Query {
    movements: [Movement!]!
    movement(id: ID!): Movement!
    workouts: [Workout!]!
    workout(id: ID!): Workout!
}

type Mutation {
  createMovement(name: String!, musclesTrained: [String!]!): Movement!
  updateMovement(id: ID!, name: String, musclesTrained: [String!]): Movement!
  deleteMovement(id: ID!): ID!
}

`;
```

I have checked if my database is running which it is. Not really sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your mutation returns a required `Movement!` type.

```
createMovement(name: String!, musclesTrained: [String!]!): Movement!
```

The `Movement` type is:

```
type Movement {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    musclesTrained: [String!]!
}
```

all 3 fields are required. Note that the 3rd field `musclesTrained` is required to be a non-null array of non-null strings.

Your mutation does:

```
const result = await pool.query(
  "INSERT INTO movements (name, musclesTrained) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *",
  [name, musclesTrained]
  );
  return result.rows[0];
```

`result.rows[0]` will return 3 columns from the db:

```
id serial PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
muscles_trained VARCHAR (255)[] NOT NULL
```

But `muscles_trained` is a `string` and not an array of strings.

Either your GraphQL `Movement` type is incorrectly defined or your database schema doesn't match the GraphQL schema. Did you mean to have a separate table for muscles and then a muscles_trained crosswalk table to join movements and muscles?

Comment: Hey Michael thanks for the response. Turns out my database schema was the problem. Thanks for the response :)